# Background song that plays on episode 242 of Bleach

Tags: music, bleach

I have been trying to find the name of the background score from the Episode 242 of *Bleach*, "Shinigami and Zanpakuto, Total Sortie" at around 4:41. It really sounds epic.

What song is that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it myself. The name of the song is Turn the tables!!